# GAE - BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine

I'm testing [Facebook's sample Google App Engine app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) by following the steps under "Getting Started".

When I try to run the app on localhost from within the Windows launcher, it waits for about 5 seconds and then displays a yellow exclamation point.  The logs give the error:

> google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `netstat -aon` and saw that the port `0.0.0.0:8080` was already in use by another process.  I changed the Facebook app configuration and the GAE settings to both point to `localhost:8888` instead, and it works!

Comment: there is an error with that commenad:netstat: illegal option -- o

Comment: @coto `netstat -o` works on Linux and Windows, but apparently not on Mac.

Answer (score 10):

**This command** will help you to delete the process using the port **:8002** without exception.

> lsof -P | grep ':8002' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Answer (score 0):

I used `lsof -P | grep ':8080'` to find the PID (the 2nd column) in Terminal, then just opened Activity Monitor, sorted by PID and forced the python process to quit.